# Как привести объект в строку и вывести результат в <input/>

Tags: javascript

Код должен разбивать строку на символы и выводит частоту буквы, но я получаю из функции `object Object` и из-за этого не могу вывести полученный результат в `input`.

Функция:

```
const counter = s => [...s].reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = a[c]+1 || 1) && a, {})

counter(encryptedMessage) //{Г: 3, Т: 3, Е: 3} - пример того что она выводит.
document.getElementById('lettersCount').value = counter(encryptedMessage)
```

Как мне эту частоту вывести в `input`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('lettersCount').value = JSON.stringify(counter(encryptedMessage));
```

---

```
document.getElementById('lettersCount').value =
  Object.entries(counter(encryptedMessage)).map(i => i.join(":")).join(" ");
```

```js
var d = { A: 2, B: 3, C: 4 };
var s = Object.entries(d).map(i => i.join(":")).join(" ");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: а можешь еще пожалуйста подсказать как это привести в читаемый вид без " " и ,? то-есть сделать его по типу Г:3  Т:3 Е:3

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Сначала приведите пример "читаемого вида".

Comment: поправил комментарий и привел

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так:

```
document.getElementById('lettersCount').value = JSON.stringify(counter(encryptedMessage))
```

но это будет не очень красиво. а вообще не понятно, что нужно вывести в инпут.
если такой объект, то как он должен выглядеть на странице?
можно вывести в несколько строк вот так:

```js
const obj = {"Г": 3, "Т": 2, "Е": 3} 
let result = ''

for (var key in obj) {
  result += `${key}: ${obj[key]}\n`
};

document.querySelector('.result').value = result;
```

```html
<textarea class="result"></textarea>
```